# How to best format thumbnails for accessibility?

Tags: accessibility, thumbnails, wai-aria, screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader

I am frequently tasked with displaying a grid of thumbnails for work, such as on a posts/articles page, with each thumbnail linking to a separate post/article, but I have never really been sure of the best way to format these for screen readers/accessibility.  More specifically, I have never been sure whether to use the <article> or <figure> tag for this purpose, or neither, or something else entirely.  Does anyone know?  These are the three methods I am debating between:

```
<a>
    <article>
        <img />
        <div></div>
    </article>
</a>

<a>
    <figure>
        <img />
        <figcaption></figcaption>
    </figure>
</a>

<a>
    <img />
    <div></div>
</a>
```

The documentation for the article tag says that it "represents a self-contained composition in a document, page, application, or site, which is intended to be independently distributable or reusable".  I don't know what that means in this context, but it seems like it could be intended for this purpose, or it could be meant to be used once on the actual article pages and not the overall "articles" list page.

The documentation for the figure tag says that it "represents self-contained content, potentially with an optional caption".  It seems like it would work quite well here, except my intuition says that it might be intended more for figures that are inline with the text of articles, so I have my doubts.

The 3rd option is to use neither the article or the figure tag in an effort to just simplify the html as much as possible so that screen readers do not have to look at and interpret as many nested tags.

**References:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/article
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure

Answer (score 1):

From an accessibility perspective, I have not found much benefit to using an `<article>`.  On iOS and Mac, Safari **incorrectly** treats an `<article>` as a landmark even though the [definition of an article role](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#article) specifically says it isn't.

> An article is not a navigational landmark, but may be nested to form a discussion where assistive technologies could pay attention to article nesting to assist the user in following the discussion.

Notice that it says AT *could* pay attention to the article element but other than the aforementioned treatment as a landmark in Safari, I have not found NVDA, JAWS, or Voiceover to do anything special with an `<article>`.

If you plan on having a caption below the image, then you could use `<figcaption>`.  It's just a handy way to visually display text below an image.  But if the thumbnail doesn't have text below it but rather has a heading or link to the article, then `<figcaption>` isn't needed.

Your last example, the simplest, is the most common way to code what you want and works just fine for accessibility. I know your code snippets were just minimal code but make sure your `<img>` uses the `alt` attribute.

If your image is inside your link (as in your example) **and** there's other text containing the title of the article within the link, then the image can have an empty `alt=""` (or even just `alt` with no value).  But if there isn't any visible text in the link, then make sure the image has an appropriate `alt` attribute value.